# How to get different colors in different columns using stack bar in python

Tags: bar-chart

Question :- How to get Alternate colors in different stacked bar using Matplotlib or Seaborn.
Say for Example - I have 3 stacked bars in a plot.
First bar should have say green, blue, yellow
Second stack bar should have orange, blue, red
Third stack bar should have blue, purple, red.

I have written the below code, it gives me the stack bar, but not the color combination as i explained above. I am getting all the 3 stack bars with same kind of colors which i don't need.

Any help..

#### TESTING PLOT 3

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

num_set = [{'USA':914, 'GBR':70, 'IND':48},
           {'USA':770, 'GBR':67, 'IND':16},
           {'USA':282, 'GBR':20, 'IND':12}]

lan_guage    = [['USA','GBR','IND'], 
               ['GBR','IND','USA'], 
               ['IND','USA','GBR']] 
colors = ["r","g","b"]
names = sorted(num_set[0].keys())
values = np.array([[data[name] for name in order] for data,order in zip(num_set, lan_guage)])
lefts = np.insert(np.cumsum(values, axis=1),0,0, axis=1)[:, :-1]
orders = np.array(lan_guage)
bottoms = np.arange(len(lan_guage))

for name, color in zip(names, colors):
    idx = np.where(orders == name)
    value = values[idx]
    left = lefts[idx]
    plt.bar(left, height=0.8, width=value, bottom=bottoms, 
    color=color, orientation="horizontal", label=name)
plt.yticks(bottoms+0.4, ["Student-%d" % (t+1) for t in bottoms])

plt.legend(loc="best", bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.00))
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
# Turn on the grid
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='green')
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 3 # No of Countries
top_sector = (914,300, 200) ## No of Investment in top sectors for C1/C2/C3
second_sector = (770,200,100) ## No of Investment in 2nd highest sector for C1/C2/C3
third_sector = (282,100,50) ## No of Investment in 3rd highest sector for C1/C2/C3
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

## p1 thru p5 are for 5 sectors.
p1 = plt.bar(ind,top_sector,width,color=['green','grey','green'])
p2 = plt.bar(ind,second_sector,width,color=['grey','green','purple'])
p3 = plt.bar(ind,third_sector,width,color=['red','brown','brown'])
p4 = plt.bar(ind,fourth_sector,width,color=['brown'])
p5 = plt.bar(ind,fifth_sector,width,color=['purple'])

plt.xlabel('Top 3 Countries for Investment')
plt.ylabel('No of Investment (Count)')
plt.title('No of Investment in top 3 sectors of top 3 countries')
plt.xticks(ind,('USA' , 'GBR', 'IND'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1000,200))
plt.legend((p1[0],p2[0],p3[0],p4[0],p5[0]),('Others',' Health', 'Entertainment', 'Cleantech / Semiconductors','News,Searching/Msg'))
plt.show()[enter image description here][1]

IMAGE :-
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9fsI.png
```